# What are the partial derivatives and Jacobian for this function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

How do you calculate the partial derivatives/Jacobian for a function of this sort using chain rule?
$$z=z(x,y)=f(3xy,\sin (xy))$$ where $f$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: State the chain rule that you know. Then write $z$ as a series of compositions. Once you do these, the problem will become clearer.

Comment: I know that $D(g(f))(a) = Dg(f(a))Df(a)$ and the partials version at the bottom of this page. I don't see how to apply them in this case. http://mathonline.wikidot.com/gradients-jacobian-matrices-and-the-chain-rule-review